# Set::extract CakePhp how to query nested anonymous arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, cakephp, filter

I have an array like

[image]

I need to get

[image]

how would i do that?

I am trying something like

Set::Extract('{n}.account_entity_id', $data )

but nothing is working. Help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do I need to suffer from some kind of colorblindness to be able to read these numbers? Anyways, how about `{n}.0.account_entity_id`?

Comment: wow! I feel like an idiot.